# Bulk URL deindex from Google search results

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-crawlers

I'm stuck with many URLs indexed by Google which does not exist ever in my website.

My WordPress website was hacked a month ago and because of this hack about 60,000+ URLs were submitted to Google and I'm getting a huge false traffic now.

What do I do to remove those URLs from Google search results?

Example URLs (some start with C and some start with G):

```
domain.com/c7123
domain.com/mum/
domain.com/c4963
domain.com/c2320
domain.com/c8380
domain.com/c3649
domain.com/c9166
domain.com/c994
domain.com/c7011
```

There is way with `.htaccess` but I'm not understanding with wild card.